Why should matrix of the linear operator $T_f$ need not be same as that of the matrix of the form $f$ for an ordered basis $\mathfrak B? $
In Hoffman and Kunze's Linear Algebra, the authors cautioned after introducing the matrix of a sesqui-linear form $f$ with respect to an arbitrary basis $\mathfrak B=\{\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n\}$ as the matrix $A$ with entries $\mathrm A_{jk}=f(\alpha_k, \alpha_j) , $

When $\mathfrak B$ is an orthonormal basis, the matrix of $f$ in $\mathfrak B$ is also the matrix of the linear transformation $T_f, $ but in general this is not the case.

Here $T_f $ is the linear operator associated with the form $f$ via Riesz representation theorem as $f(\alpha, \beta) =(T\alpha\mid\beta)~~\forall~\alpha, \beta\in\mathbf V. $
It seems they didn't expand the comment further in the subsequent section.
I would appreciate if anyone is able to shed some light on this. This seems to be apparently correct but somehow I am not able to comprehend that as to how/why this is so. Perhaps an example in same vein would be helpful.

It boils down to the fact that the common dot/inner-product formula $\xi=\sum_{i=1}^n\langle \xi, \alpha_i\rangle\,\alpha_i$ is only true when the basis is orthonormal. If the basis is merely orthogonal, then you need to divide by $\|\alpha_i\|^2$. If the basis is not even orthogonal, then the inner product doesn’t even play a role so there’s no simple formula like this (more precisely, there’s no simple explicit formula for the dual basis of a given basis).
With this in mind, just compute what the matrix of $T_f$ is relative to the given orthonormal basis. Just unwind the definitions and you’ll get the desired result.

Thanks for the answer. So the authors are telling that when your basis is not orthonormal, you can't expect the two respective matrices to be same as there would be no such formula that you mentioned at the beginning. Is it so or is there something else?

Yes that’s essentially what they’re saying. Also, this is related to the fact that the matrix representation of the adjoint operator (on an inner product space) equals the conjugate transpose of the matrix of the original operator if the basis is orthonormal, but not necessarily otherwise.

That's legit. Thanks for the insight.

Let $[T_f]_{\mathfrak B}=(T_{jk})_{i,j\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}}$ be the matrix representation of $T_f$ with respect to the ordered basis $\mathfrak B$. This means
$$
T_f\alpha_k=\sum_{i}T_{ik}\alpha_i
$$
for each $k$. It follows from the definition of $A$ and $T_f$ that
$$
A_{jk}
=f(\alpha_k,\alpha_j)
=(T_f\alpha_k|\alpha_j)
=(\sum_{i}T_{ik}\alpha_i|\alpha_j)
=\sum_{i}T_{ik}(\alpha_i|\alpha_j).
$$
Therefore, if we define a matrix $B=(B_{ji})$ by $B_{ji}=(\alpha_i|\alpha_j)$, then
$$
A_{jk}
=\sum_{i}T_{ik}(\alpha_i|\alpha_j)
=\sum_{i}B_{ji}T_{ik}
$$
for every $(j,k)$. In matrix form, this means precisely that $A=B[T_f]_{\mathfrak B}$.
The basis $\mathfrak B$ is orthonormal if and only if $B_{ji}=(\alpha_i|\alpha_j)=\delta_{ji}$ for each $(j,i)$, i.e., if and only if $B=I_n$. So, if $\mathfrak B$ is not an orthonormal basis, then $B\ne I_n$ and $A=B[T_f]_{\mathfrak B}$ is not necessarily equal to $[T_f]_{\mathfrak B}$.

Thanks for the nice answer, as it is the reaffirmation of what peek-a-boo said. +1.
